# Using ResourceDictionary from a DLL in Windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-8, app-store

How can I use the ResourceDictionary resource from the same DLL?

Basically I am trying to create a UI library with all classes derived from Page class. I want to keep all user interface pages in the same DLL.

To see the problem, from VS2012, create a Windows 8 library project, then add the Item Detailed Page. Now, if you open the created page from the editor, you will get some errors like "The resource "LayoutRootStyle" could not be resolved".

Answer (score 0):

This is just a Xaml Designer error, so that will not prevent your project from building or running . 
The only thing needed is that all the ResourceDictonary need to be referenced by the main application App.xaml (for example by using `<ResourceDictionary Source="/<myLibraryName>/Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>` or by creating calling an Init method in the Library which will dynamically add the Resource dictionary). 
A quick workaround for the error in the Xaml Designer is to just copy an App.xaml/App.xaml.cs in your library (but at runtime the main application will still need to have a reference on the needed ResourceDictionary since the App.xaml of the library will not be used). 
Another posibility is to just add a refrence on the ResourceDictionary on each page but I believe that will be much more costly since it will create an instance of the dictionary for each page.